# Modbus TCP Communication C#

Tags: c#, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am looking for a little help. 
I have a program to communicate with a controller through Modbus TCP. 
The only problem is I cannot extend the Nop from 125 to 400 because I got Illegal Data Address error message.
Could you please help me with this?

```
            try
        {
            byte slaveid = 1;
            byte function = 4;
            ushort id = function;

            ushort startAddress = 0;
            uint NoP = 125;

            byte[] frame = ReadInputRegistersMsg(id, slaveid, startAddress, function, NoP);
            this.Write(frame); //data send to controller
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            byte[] buffReceiver = this.Read(); //data recieving from controller
            int SizeByte = buffReceiver[8]; // Data what I got from the controller
            UInt16[] temp = null;

            if (function != buffReceiver[7])
            {
                byte[] byteMsg = new byte[9];
                Array.Copy(buffReceiver, 0, byteMsg, 0, byteMsg.Length);
                byte[] data = new byte[SizeByte];
                textBox2.Text = Display(byteMsg);

                byte[] errorbytes = new byte[3];
                Array.Copy(buffReceiver, 6, errorbytes, 0, errorbytes.Length);
                this.CheckValidate(errorbytes); // check the answer -> error message
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] byteMsg = new byte[9 + SizeByte];
                Array.Copy(buffReceiver, 0, byteMsg, 0, byteMsg.Length);
                byte[] data = new byte[SizeByte];
                textBox2.Text = Display(byteMsg); // Show received messages in windows form app
                Array.Copy(buffReceiver, 9, data, 0, data.Length);
                temp = Word.ConvertByteArrayToWordArray(data); // Convert Byte[]-> Word[]
            }
            // Result
            if (temp == null) return;
            string result = string.Empty;
            //foreach (var item in temp) // show all the data
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++) // show the first 100 data
            {
                //result += string.Format("{0} ", item);
                result += temp[i];
            }
            textBox3.Text = result; // insert the result into the textbox (windows form app)

        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

The ReadInputRegister Message is the following:

```
private byte[] ReadInputRegistersMsg(ushort id, byte slaveAddress, ushort startAddress, byte function, uint NoP)
        {
            byte[] frame = new byte[12];
            frame[0] = (byte)(id >> 8); // Transaction Identifier High
            frame[1] = (byte)id; // Transaction Identifier Low
            frame[2] = 0; // Protocol Identifier High
            frame[3] = 0; // Protocol Identifier Low
            frame[4] = 0; // Message Length High
            frame[5] = 6; // Message Length Low(6 bytes to follow)
            frame[6] = slaveAddress; // Slave address(Unit Identifier)
            frame[7] = function; // Function             
            frame[8] = (byte)(startAddress >> 8); // Starting Address High
            frame[9] = (byte)startAddress; // Starting Address Low           
            frame[10] = (byte)(NoP >> 8); // Quantity of Registers High
            frame[11] = (byte)NoP; // Quantity of Registers Low
            return frame;
        }
```

Comment: The only place `NoP` is used is as a parameter to a method we can't see (`ReadInputRegistersMsg`). Is that where the exception is happening? or...?

Comment: I refreshed the question! @MarcGravell

Comment: What's giving you a 'Illegal Data Address' error message- the device you're sending the frame to ?

Comment: Finally I found a description in wikipedia:

Function code 4 (read input registers) and function code 3 (read holding registers)
Request:

Address of first register to read (16-bit)
Number of registers to read (16-bit)
Normal response:

Number of bytes of register values to follow (8-bit)
Register values (16 bits per register)
Because the number of bytes for register values is 8-bit wide and maximum modbus message size is 256 bytes, only 125 registers for Modbus RTU and 123 registers for Modbus TCP can be read at once.[13]

Comment: so basically: 125 is a hard limit imposed by the protocol? just checking that there's nothing else you're looking for here...?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, I have to create another modbus communication to get the next 125 Points. I think That is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The hard limit for modbus is 125 NoP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SihD.png)